# Linux live cd with Broadcom Wi-fi support

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, broadcom

I am looking for a live distro that has out of the box Broadcom wireless support. I am pretty happy with my Ubuntu installation and as long as I have an ethernet connection first time installed, I can install Broadcom drivers over internet.

But being a little paranoid, I make my secure operations (banking etc.) with a live cd and zero hard disk access, so nothing is recorded. So far I plug ethernet to do such things with the live cd, but it would be nice if I can do same thing with wireless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Crunchbang, it seems to work automagically. You can't use UnetBootIn to create the live USB however.

See:

- [A quick look at Crunchbang](http://charlesmccolm.com/2012/07/24/a-quick-look-at-crunchbang/)
- [Copy a CrunchBang 10 or Crunchbang 11 ISO image to USB in Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/statler_usb_installation)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Live CD, why not use a Live USB with some persistence? Boot the Live USB on a computer with both Ethernet and Wireless then install the wireless drivers. Next time you boot without the Ethernet, the distro will have the drivers already installed and should run the wireless.

This will create a Linux Live USB with persistence from almost any distro you can image. There are even some specialty distros that focus on security. They are set up to always use secure connections, encrypt everything, and intentionally leave no trace.

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/